# Redirect loop with similar URLs

Tags: redirect

I want to redirect a page that ends in mysite.com/fall to mysite.com/fall-2019

I've renamed the original page permalink of mysite.com/fall to  mysite.com/fall-old and to a 301 in the .htaccess that reads...

```
RedirectMatch 301 /fall http://kadampafestivals.org/fall-2019
```

It redirects to the link by then the page says there is a redirection loop. I assume because that redirect is reading the /fall part from the new URL still. How can I make the redirect exclusive to that page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RedirectMatch` is very helpful if you want to redirect according to regular expression or similar. This is not needed here, and could be the very reason of your problem. Try the following instead

```
Redirect 301    /fall    /fall-2019
```